# How to find i largest numbers in unsorted array in O(n) where i <= n^(1/2)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

If we have length $n$ unsorted array such that each element is integer and different, how to find $i$ largest numbers in linear time O(n)? but $i \leq n^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

For example, if we have $A = [11, 6, 8, 1, 9, 100, 88]$ and input $i = 2$, then output is $[100, 88]$ (sorted).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the $i$th largest number.  This can be done in linear time.  Then, do a second scan over the array to find all numbers larger than the $i$th largest number.  (With many selection algorithms, this last step is unnecessary, as they partition the array into elements smaller than the $i$th largest and larger than the $i$th largest.)

Comment: How can I apply this algorithm to this finding multiple largest numbers problem?

Comment: @t24akeru, see edited answer.  You should be able to work out the details from here.

Comment: @D.M. Thank you! One question, is the scanning operation not counted time complexity?

Comment: I would like to add that the classical selection algorithms (quickselect / median of medians) both partition the array so that the largest $i$ elements are also the last elements if you select on the $i$th element.